# Getting spacing right with hangindent

Tags: spacing, indentation, glue

I want a definition to hang to the right of the symbol being defined (in this case, the `$\chi...$` stuff).  Here is what I wrote:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

{%
  \leftskip=\parindent\rightskip=\parindent%
  \parindent=0pt%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\chi^*(H, w) =$ }%
  \hangindent=\wd0\hangafter1%
  \advance\hangindent by1pt%
  $\chi^*(H, w) =$ minimum of~$\lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_k$,
  where~$\lambda_1$, \dots,~$\lambda_k \geq 0$ and there are
  independent sets~$I_1$, \dots,~$I_k$ such
  that~$\lambda_1 \chi_{I_1} + \cdots + \lambda_k \chi_{I_k} = w$.

}

\end{document}
```

Without the `advance\hangindent by1pt` above, the second line starts a little bit to the left of where it should.  I have the impression that what is messing this up is the stretching glue in spaces between words, but I have tried to prevent this to no avail.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to an MWE, which we can test as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the spaces in the formula participate in stretching or shrinking for justification, whereas in the box you measure the hanging indent with those spaces are fixed.

You need to “freeze” those spaces and I suggest defining an environment for such kind of thing.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\explainformulawidth}
\newenvironment{explainformula}[1]
 {%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \leftskip=\parindent
  \rightskip=\parindent
  \parindent=0pt
  \settowidth{\explainformulawidth}{$#1={}$}%
  \hangindent=\explainformulawidth
  \hangafter=1
  ${#1={}}$\ignorespaces
 }
 {\par\addvspace{\topsep}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{explainformula}{\chi^*(H, w)}
  minimum of~$\lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_k$,
  where~$\lambda_1$, \dots,~$\lambda_k \geq 0$ and there are
  independent sets~$I_1$, \dots,~$I_k$ such
  that~$\lambda_1 \chi_{I_1} + \cdots + \lambda_k \chi_{I_k} = w$.
\end{explainformula}

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}
```

Note that the formula is input with braces around it when it's time to typeset it and the space after the equals sign is provided by `{}`.

[image]

Comment: This is great!  But please, explain the magic: why does this "freeze" the spaces?  Is it because of the expansion of #1?

Comment: @Fernando When you type `${a=b}$` TeX thinks you want a “subformula” so the spaces in it are at their natural size and are not subject to stretching and shrinking for justification. When TeX transforms the math list into boxes, it adds a level of boxing to subformulas.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Right. I'll do it in a more LaTeX way.

Comment: I didn't like so much that the *key* being defined (in this case the `\chi` etc) was hardcoded as math in the environment, that is, you type the formula without $ when you do `begin{...}` and you add the $ in the environment (then it only works with math).  I figured out the same works if you use `\hbox{#1}`, but I had to add a 0 width `\vrule` before the `\hbox` or it occupied a line by itself.  Don't understand why.

Comment: @Fernando Please, add information on what you plan to set in the left part. Anyway, use `\mbox` and not `\hbox`.